# RequiredScope attribute doesn't have any effect

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, policy-based-security

I have implemented an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API using .NET 8.0.202.

I have added the following HttpGet action to the default `WeatherForecastController`

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("onlyfortestscope")]
[RequiredScope("TestScope")]
public string OnlyForTestScope()
{
    return "You have access to this API";
    //https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/issues/1571
}
```

`WebApplication` builder code looks like this

```
builder.Services.AddRequiredScopeAuthorization();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(o => builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", o));
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(config =>
{
    /*
    //None of this configuration is working!
    config.AddPolicy("default", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        //policy.RequireScope("CardReader TestScope");
        //policy.RequireScope("api://d269eec9-5d0a-409d-bf69-0426237a7153/TestScope");
        //policy.RequireClaim("CardReader TestScope");
        //policy.RequireClaim("api://d269eec9-5d0a-409d-bf69-0426237a7153/TestScope");
    });*/

});

var app = builder.Build();

...

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
```

My access token (JWT token) contains following scope

```
"scp": "CardReader TestScope"
```

I am expecting that since the JWT token has `TestScope` in it, it should be able to invoke the action `onlyfortestscope`.

But, any valid JWT token is able to invoke this API endpoint.  e.g. following `onlyfortestscope` action is accessible even if `AnyRandomScope` is missing in JWT token.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("onlyfortestscope")]
[RequiredScope("AnyRandomScope")]
public string OnlyForTestScope()
{
    return "You have access to this API";
    //https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/issues/1571
}
```

I found [this](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/issues/1571) similar closed issue but in vain.

Any pointers?

Comment: If you have defined your policy and called it `Default` (with `policy.RequireClaim("TestScope");`), then your action method should have an annotation `[HttpGet(Policy = "Default")]` to require that policy. Did you try that?

Comment: Yes,  I tried that.  It has no effect.  Hence I used [RequiredScope("TestScope")] instead of policy.

Comment: Can you paste the screenshot of the API permissions granted to the application in Portal?